# Unable to send emails. Could not acquire lock for cron job: sales_send_order_invoice_emails

Tags: magento2, order-email, contact-us, contact-form, cronjobs

Unable to send any kind emails (order, invoice, tracking). I get confirmation that it was sent, but nothing received. Same with "Contact us" from frontend.

cron.log:

`main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: sales_send_order_emails`

`main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: sales_send_order_shipment_emails`

`main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: sales_send_order_invoice_emails`

`main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup`

`main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: bulk_cleanup`

Permissions are correct (i think):
[image]
[image]

Magento 2.3.5-p2, PHP 7.2

Problem persisted after upgrade to Magento 2.4 and PHP 7.3 and 7.4

Couldn't find much online about "Could not acquire lock for cron job".

Any help will do.

Comment: Have you checked M2 core source code for this sentence: "Could not acquire lock for cron job"? Have you tried to run cron manually with magerun using a step by step with Xdebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was fault with permissions in

`/var/spool/mqueue`

and

`/var/spool/mqueue-client`

Changing permissions got rid of these errors.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I guess Magento cron job is stuck in "running" status. Need to kill the stuck cron job then it will continue as scheduled.

1. Log in to your account using SSH.
2. Run the following command to locate hanging cron jobs: `$ ps ufx | grep cron`
3. To stop the cron from running, kill the command by referencing the PID. Run the following command to terminate the command: `$ kill -9 PID`

For more detail, please refer to these links:
[Link-1](https://help.nexcess.net/magento/how-to-find-and-remove-hanging-magento-cron-jobs-with-ssh)
[Link-2](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033099451-Cron-job-is-stuck-in-running-status)

Comment: No hanging cron jobs. Did this before posting question.

Comment: This is the most likely scenario if you are facing this issue. Killing the stuck process solve these case. This free module made by Mageplaza is also helpful: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-cron-schedule/